# node.js - node-fetch returns null when cookies are received

Tags: node.js, cookies, fetch

I have a code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('https://www.instagram.com/', {method: 'GET',  credentials: 'same-origin'})
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res.headers.get('set-cookie'));
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I want to get `cookies` from the response, but `res.headers.get('set-cookie')` returns `null`.
I tried:
`res.headers['set-cookie']; //undefined`
`res.headers['cookie'] //undefined`
`res.headers.raw()['set-cookie']; //undefined`
set: `credentials: 'include' //also don't work`

I do not know what the problem is, I tried everything, please help.

Answer (score -1):

I meet that too. The official document says that credentials are not supported.
[offical document](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#class-request)